# Javascript - window.onresize for pinch-zooming

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, zooming

I am creating a website where the main layout is something like this:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="content">
        Text goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

I have made it so that the content div is always vertically and horizontally centered within the container. I have triggered the centering at `window.onload` and `window.onresize`. I thought it was ok until I realised when I pinch zoom on Chrome for Android (haven't tried other browsers yet) it does **not** call `window.onresize` and my layout becomes totally messed up until `window.onresize` is called.

(I want to try not to use setInterval to center the content as it will either not be instant or not be very efficient.)

I was wondering if there was a Javascript function which is executed everytime the user zooms or if there were any variables which will change as the user zooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` change when the user zooms.